# Include those groups which are not present as zero

Tags: sql, count

I have a query as below which outputs sum only when records of column `booklet_type` are present. It groups results on types like 'GR' and 'PI'.

For instance, if GR has `end_leaf_no` and `start_leaf_no` as '5' and '4' and same for `PI` then records will be displayed on matching booking_date like,

GR  2

PI  2

But, these does not return any records for 0 occurences of booklets of specific type. I want it as,

GR 0

PI 0

How do I go about accomplishing this result? I tried case when in select clause but to no avail.

Thanks.

```
Select Booklet_type, SUM(End_Leaf_No -  Start_Leaf_No +1) as No_of_Coupons  

from Coupon_Sale 

where date_format(Booklet_Sale_Date, '%Y%m') = :ccyymm 
      and Booklet_type = “GR” or “PI” 
group by Booklet_Type
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a `left outer join` and a subquery that generates the rows you want.  The following works in most databases:

```
Select driver.Booklet_type, SUM(cs.End_Leaf_No -  cs.Start_Leaf_No +1) as No_of_Coupons  
from (select 'GR' as Booklet_type union all
      select 'PI'
     ) driver left outer join
     Coupon_Sale cs
     on driver.Booklet_Type = cs.Booklet_Type and
        date_format(cs.Booklet_Sale_Date, '%Y%m') = :ccyymm and
        cs.Booklet_type in ('GR', 'PI')
group by driver.Booklet_Type;
```

To make this work, I moved the `where` conditions into the `on` clause.