# Add to the rows of union query

Tags: mysql, union

I have this query where I unioned results and then performed group by on them. I have it answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18023167/include-those-groups-which-are-not-present-as-zero). Pasting it below too:

```
Select driver.Booklet_type, SUM(cs.End_Leaf_No -  cs.Start_Leaf_No +1) as No_of_Coupons  
from (select 'GR' as Booklet_type union all
  select 'PI'
 ) driver left outer join
 Coupon_Sale cs
 on driver.Booklet_Type = cs.Booklet_Type and
    date_format(cs.Booklet_Sale_Date, '%Y%m') = :ccyymm and
    cs.Booklet_type in ('GR', 'PI')
group by driver.Booklet_Type;
```

The results I get are of the form:

```
Booklet_Type   |  No_of_Coupons     
========================   
GR             |  3
PI             |  1
```

Now I have another query which is grouped by on amount and has results like:

```
Amount         |  Count 
========================
25             |  3
10             |  1
```

Now I would like to add the count of 3 to the GR row above from above table and 1 to the PI row likewise.

How do I do this?

The query for second table is:

```
select payment_amount,count(p_id) 
  from p 
 where p_id in (463,464,465,466,467,468,469,470,471,472,473,474,475,476)
 group by payment_amount
```

Comment: How does your application know that the counts for GR and 25 get summed? Same question for PI and 10.

Comment: They both (GR and PI) are considered as per requirements to be coupons of denominations 25 and 10 respectively. From other table p_id has denominations (payment_amount) 25 and 10. This payment_amount count has to be aggregated to corresponding GR and PI coupon amount. Ultimately a report  is to be shown of these categories.

Comment: Are those business rules (GR = 25, PI = 15) in a table someplace? That will help you create the best queries.